# App Sending Old Pushes With New Ones

Tags: ios, push-notification, apple-push-notifications

My ios apps started acting funny. When I send a Push Notification through, on the home screen, it's also showing older push's that I have sent.

Example: If I send a push now, it will go through, but also bring up 3 older pushes below and say the date they were sent "28 days ago".

I've never seen anything like this with any other apps and it's really making things difficult for me.

It happens on iPhone & iPad, iOS 6 & 7.

Has anyone seen this before or can point me into the right direction as to what the problem is.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I've been having the same problem that I could always reproduce on a few devices here and I think I just solved it.

I was using the enhanced format of the push API (command 1, found at the link below) and how I fixed it was I noticed the "identifier" I was sending was always 0.

https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/NetworkingInternet/Conceptual/RemoteNotificationsPG/Chapters/LegacyFormat.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40008194-CH105-SW5

After changing this to a randomly generated number for each new push, the devices no longer re-displays the older pushes when a new push is received.

Let me know if this fixes it as I've seen this pop up quite a bit on other forums, with no real resolutions posted as far as I can tell.